# Configuring Message Broker to use a proxy

Tags: messagebroker, broker

My organization recently implemented a new proxy/firewall appliance and now I find that my development broker instance (WMB version 8.0.0.1) is unable to call external web services.

Does anyone have any experience in configuring the broker to use a proxy?

If the web service I was trying to call were being served via HTTP, I suspect that routing traffic through a TCP/IP Monitor in Toolkit would solve the problem (as Toolkit is proxy-aware), but the one I need to call at the moment is being served via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what sort of proxy you are using.

There are essentially 2 possible setups, in the first instance you will make an ssl connection to the proxy and the proxy will make an ssl connection on the client (brokers) behalf to the remote server.

In the second scenario you will make an unsecured tcp/ip connection to the proxy and use this as a tunnel to make an ssl connection from the client (Broker) to the remote server. To use this option you need to fill in the "HTTP(S) proxy location" in the request node properties.

Comment: The second scenario is what I want to do. Setting the proxy on the request node does work, though I was hoping there would be a broker-wide setting so I didn't have to set it on each and every request node. I could see problems arising when we needed to build a BAR for our testing MB server (that isn't subject to the proxy) and forgetting to remove the proxy settings on the request nodes.

Thank you very much for your answer. I had already opened a PMR with IBM about this as I'm hoping there's a broker-wide setting somewhere but assuming there's not, I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: As well as raising a PMR you could consider opening a request for enhancement at the following URL: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532 Sounds like an EG property could be  a useful new feature.

Comment: I'm still in touch with IBM on this, but there doesn't appear to be a EG-level or broker-level proxy setting. Thank you again for your answer.